# Journey Builder & SF Campaign Member entry event

Tags: journeybuilder, campaign, campaign-member

I have a journey (simple one, just a couple of sends)
My entry point, is a SF campaign entry event. Basically adding a member to the campaign adds the contact to the journey. Did this in the past and works fine.

But I came to a situation that I have a new journey like this, but I have no contacts (zero) evaluated for journey entry, no matter how many times I add a member to the SF campaign.

Ideas to troubleshoot?